# Accessing GraphDB with RDF4J with an specific user

Tags: security, graphdb, rdf4j

I'm using RDF4J to add RDF triples to a completely open (Security off) GraphDB instance. I use the `RemoteRepositoryManager` and it works fine:

```
RepositoryManager repositoryManager = new RemoteRepositoryManager(GraphDBInstanceURL);
Repository repository = repositoryManager.getRepository(graphDBrepoName);
RepositoryConnection repositoryConnection = repository.getConnection();
```

Now we need to add security to GraphDB, but it is not clear to me how to add the specific GraphDB user credentials in the above code. Any pointers are wellcome, thanks

Comment: Does the documentation at https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/access-control.html#basic-authentication helps a bit? 
E.g. depending on the particular security setup/details, the easiest way is to obtain an authorisation token and then use it as an additional header within your client.
HTH